# velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered "<EOF>" at <unknown template> when #end is followed by _

Tags: java, velocity

I get the following error when evaluating a velocity template.

```
Encountered "<EOF>" at <unknown template>[line 1, column 170]
Was expecting one of:
    "[" ...
    "(" ...
    <RPAREN> ...
    <ESCAPE_DIRECTIVE> ...
    <SET_DIRECTIVE> ...
    "##" ...
    "\\\\" ...
    "\\" ...
    <TEXT> ...
    "*#" ...
    "*#" ...
    "]]#" ...
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    <END> ...
    <IF_DIRECTIVE> ...
    <ELSEIF_DIRECTIVE> ...
    <ELSE_DIRECTIVE> ...
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <WORD> ...
    <BRACKETED_WORD> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <DOT> ...
    "{" ...
    "}" ...
    <EMPTY_INDEX> ...
    <DOT> ...
```

The template I am evaluating is this.

```
${fileName}_#if( $noticeType == 'typeA' )TypeAlpha#elseif( $noticeType == 'typeB' )TypeBeta#end_$date.format('yyyyMMdd', $myDate)
```

I need the whole string to be without spaces and to follow the format of `fileName_TypeAlpha_20200423`, so my issue is with `#end_`. The underscore is causing velocity to ignore the #end, so it cannot evaluate the if else statement.

How can I perform the #if #elseif #end and follow that immediately by an `_` without spaces?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer.

I need to wrap the end in curly brackets to distinguish it from the rest of the text.

`#{end}_`

So my template is

```
${fileName}_#if( $noticeType == 'typeA' )TypeAlpha#elseif( $noticeType == 'typeB' )TypeBeta#{end}_$date.format('yyyyMMdd', $myDate)
```

See the very end of http://people.apache.org/~henning/velocity/html/ch05s03.html